# Python Script skipping rows

Tags: python, csv

I have a following procedure that I would like to automate, assign a specific pool of IPs to certain systems following these guidelines:
1. skip first 10 IPs 
2. populate each subnet with IPs

I'm using Python 3.5.1
Im working from csv files and here is the sample of data I work with:

- Net           STACK        System    Unit   Room
- 10.0.28.0     CAB_DS4-2_2
- 10.0.28.32    CAB_DS4-2_2
- 10.0.28.64    CAB_DS4-1_1
- 10.0.28.96    CAB_DS4-1_2
- 10.0.28.128   CAB_DS3-2_1
- 10.0.28.160   CAB_DS3-3_1
- 10.0.28.192   CAB_DS3-3_2
- 10.0.28.224   CAB_DS2-2_1

here is the code I made, it works for exactly half of the data, out of 8 subnets it assigns only 4 . Here is the code:

```
import csv
import ipaddress

with open('sorted2.csv') as csv_file:
    ip_pool = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(ip_pool)

    for row in ip_pool:
        ip = ipaddress.ip_address(row[0])
        nextROW = next(ip_pool)
        ip_end = nextROW[0] #NEXT network limit
        counter = 0

        ip_end = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_end)
        ip_next = ip + 9 # skip first 10 IPs
        ip_assign = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_next)

        print ('NEW NET:', ip)
        while ipaddress.ip_address(ip_assign) < ipaddress.ip_address(ip_end)-1:
            counter += 1 # count number of IPs assigned, to be implemented later
            ip_assign = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_assign)+1 #iterate next IP
            ip_start = ip_assign

            print(ip_assign)
        ip_next = ip_assign
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
NEW NET: 10.0.28.0
10.0.28.10
10.0.28.11
10.0.28.12
10.0.28.13
10.0.28.14
10.0.28.15
10.0.28.16
10.0.28.17
10.0.28.18
10.0.28.19
10.0.28.20
10.0.28.21
10.0.28.22
10.0.28.23
10.0.28.24
10.0.28.25
10.0.28.26
10.0.28.27
10.0.28.28
10.0.28.29
10.0.28.30
10.0.28.31
NEW NET: 10.0.28.64
10.0.28.74
10.0.28.75
10.0.28.76
10.0.28.77
10.0.28.78
10.0.28.79
10.0.28.80
10.0.28.81
10.0.28.82
10.0.28.83
10.0.28.84
10.0.28.85
10.0.28.86
10.0.28.87
10.0.28.88
10.0.28.89
10.0.28.90
10.0.28.91
10.0.28.92
10.0.28.93
10.0.28.94
10.0.28.95
NEW NET: 10.0.28.128
10.0.28.138
10.0.28.139
10.0.28.140
10.0.28.141
10.0.28.142
10.0.28.143
10.0.28.144
10.0.28.145
10.0.28.146
10.0.28.147
10.0.28.148
10.0.28.149
10.0.28.150
10.0.28.151
10.0.28.152
10.0.28.153
10.0.28.154
10.0.28.155
10.0.28.156
10.0.28.157
10.0.28.158
10.0.28.159
NEW NET: 10.0.28.192
10.0.28.202
10.0.28.203
10.0.28.204
10.0.28.205
10.0.28.206
10.0.28.207
10.0.28.208
10.0.28.209
10.0.28.210
10.0.28.211
10.0.28.212
10.0.28.213
10.0.28.214
10.0.28.215
10.0.28.216
10.0.28.217
10.0.28.218
10.0.28.219
10.0.28.220
10.0.28.221
10.0.28.222
10.0.28.223
```

As you can see, it skips 4 of the subnets, and I cant seem to put my finger on what I coded wrong/forgot. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're modifying `ip_pool` whilst iterating over it, by calling `next(ip_pool)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't modify `ip_pool` while you are iterating over it.

Instead of iterating rows and trying to get the next whilst iterating, keep track of the previous row (we can still name it `row`), but our iteration will be over the next row, instead of the current row:

```
row = next(ip_pool)
for nextROW in ip_pool:
    ...
    row = nextROW
```

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean just not sure how to implement the fix you are hinting in my code

Comment: I'm not sure what else to explain. At the start of your loop replace it with the start of the loop I've posted. At the end of the loop add the `row = nextROW` line. The `...` should stay the same, although you should remove your line `nextROW = next(ip_pool)` as the value for `nextROW` is already taken care of.